# Is there way to declare multiple inheritance in a generic Dart method?

Tags: dart

I have the following inheritance structure in Dart code, and am wondering whether there is a method signature that accounts for both class A and class B for T, so that I have a static check and don't have to typecast.  Is this possible?

```
   abstract class A {
      String one;
    }
    abstract class B {
      String two;
    }

    class C implements A, B {
      String one;
      String two;
    }

    class D implements A, B {
      String one;
      String two;
    }

    void _ohNo<T extends A, B>(T t) {
      print(t.one); // valid
      print(t.two); // invalid: getter not defined
    }

    void _ohNo2<T extends A, T extends B>(T t) {} // invalid: T already defined
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to have multiple type constaints on a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61820181/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-type-constaints-on-a-generic-type)

Answer (score 0):

Could be a workaround:

```
abstract class Both extends A with B {}                                                                                                                                                                                                 

class C implements Both {                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  String one = '';                                                                                                                                                                                  
  String two = '';                                                                                                                                                                                   
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

class D implements Both {                                                                                                                                                                                                               
   String one = '';                                                                                                                                                                                   
   String two = '';                                                                                                                                                                           
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
void ohNo<T extends Both>(T t) {                                                                                                                                                                                                        
   print(t.one);                                                                                                                                                                                                                
   print(t.two);
}
```