# Is it possible to have multiple type constaints on a generic type?

Tags: generics, dart, type-constraints

In dart you can do

```
class Preference<T extends int>
```

to define a type constraint. But is there a way to define multiple constrains?

I tried

```
class Preference<T extends int, String>
```

But an error get's thrown when I try to pass a argument of type T to a function that excepts a String saying

> The argument type 'T' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Comment: What would you want to achieve with this?

Comment: Just wanted to know if it was possible

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, Dart type parameters can only have a single constraint. There is no workaround.

Comment: that is terrible